# With Rails, can I use a single table to store simple values (gender, hair color, eye color)?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have a Person table that stores information about that person (weird right?). I have select boxes for things like gender, hair color, and eye color. Instead of creating separate tables with a description field for each, is there a good way to use a single table? Maybe a Resources table with a Name and Description fields? Is it just that simple?

```
Resources
=========
ID    Name       Description
--------------------
1     Gender     Male
2     Gender     Female
3     Eye Color  Blue
4     Eye Color  Green
5     Eye Color  Brown
6     Hair Color Black
7     Hair Color Brunette
8     Hair Color Blonde
9     Hair Color Red

Person
=========
ID  Name  Gender  Eye_Color  Hair_Color
-----------------------------------------------
1   Ryan  1       3          8
```

Is this the recommended way or is there something better for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is that simple, IMO your approach is correct. But please note you approach will not work if you get to select Ex: multiple hair colors for one person.

But I believe keeping code simple until you get a requirement to change it, read about [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it) when u have some time :)

Comment: Yep, I understand this is only good for a one to one and that I'd need a bridge table for a one to many. I think this is the route I will be taking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it that way and it would be a polymorphic association.

If you don't need to query this information but just be able to access it you can use serialize and just store all the values in one column.
So a person record would have a column, let's call it attributes, that would have "eye_color: blue, gender: male", etc...

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a separate table called Physical_attributes and an assossiative one between Person and Physical_attributes, personal_physical_attributes, where I'd store the person's id, the Physical_attribute's id and the description for that Physical_attribute.